Caractère de ce qui est correct
En philosophie, on distingue les arguments valides des arguments corrects (les hypothèses des premiers ne sont pas nécessairement vraies). Cela correspond à la distinction entre valid et sound en anglais.
On peut ainsi parler de la validité d'un argument, et de sa… correction? correctité?

Correction. Ce que consulter un dictionnaire aurait pu confirmer facilement.

@Frank Les Roumains disent parfois correctitude :-)

@jlliagre Bon, je veux bien, mais alors quelle est la différence entre correctitude et exactitude?

@Frank Sensiblement la même qu'entre bravitude et bravoure ! ;-)

On exprime souvent a sound argument en philosophie par un « argument fondé » (c'est à dire qui repose sur des faits assurés, vérifiables, qui est correct) et on parle de la fondation d'un raisonnement. C'est peut-être ça que tu cherches ?

@None Non le terme technique est "argument correct". Voir par exemple ce cours

@Frank Je suis venu poser une question, pas recevoir du mépris. J'ai consulté le Littré pour "correction", le seul sens rapprochant de "caractère de ce qui est correct" est le 7ème (!), le Gaffiot (pour "correctio") ne donne rien qui va dans ce sens

Le cours cité en référence commence mal à mon sens: "toute connaissance est une croyance vraie et justifiée". "JTB" en anglais, mais ce n'est vraiment pas la seule façon de voir la "connaissance". Il faudrait approfondir chacun des termes, et considérer des positions alternatives. Le concept de "vérité" lui-même est de toute façon un peu surfait aussi ou mal compris ;-)

La différence entre correctitude et exactitude, c'est sûrement la même qu'entre correction et exaction?

@Xenophon Bienvenue sur fr.SE. Pour qui a le français comme langue maternelle, c'est une surprise que le sens qualité de ce qui est correct ne vienne qu'après 6 variations sur action de corriger ou son résultat dans les dictionnaires. La question gagnerait à le préciser.


En philosophie, on distingue les arguments valides des arguments corrects (les hypothèses des premiers ne sont pas nécessairement vraies).

I think that is the opposite, arguments called valid are considered true and arguments called correct are considered, uhm, correct.    Although valid and correct are often synonyms, the character of correct is nearly a type of contronym.  For example, the writings of Nostradamus are called valid by some and correct by others. Those who say the writings are valid are saying the predictions were absolute truth.  Those who say the writings are correct are also implying corrections are needed because some of his predictions weren’t valid.   So with philosophical works (or elsewhere), valid tends to be an absolute truth, whereas correct ALSO means “the truth” might need some corrections.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
